# Concatenate two columns, look for duplicates copy single row to new worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I have an Excel or CSV file with 5,000 rows and 20 columns.
I want to concatenate *Column* 6 and *Column 8*, look for duplicates and then copy only one of the duplicates into WorkSheet2.

**For Example**:

Worksheet1

```
Column6  Column7     Column 8
 
275s     ABC         123

333s     ABC         111

275s     ZZZ         123

275s     DSD         123

333s     ???         111

275s     asd         999
```

The result of concatenate Column 6 and column 8 will render that rows 1,3 and 4 are duplicates.

Row 2 and 5 are duplicates also.

Then worksheet2 should be:

```
Column6  Column7     Column 8
 
275s     ABC         123

333s     ABC         111
 
275s     asd         999
```

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate? Same value for Column6? Which value should be in Column7 abc, zzz or dsd. This can be done without VBA too.

Comment: Also, this isn't a script-writing service. Show us what you've done and we can help you figure out where your problems are.

Comment: Column 7 is just there for filler .. only column 6 and 8 matter for comparison.

Comment: dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare 'NOT case sensitive. omit for case sensitive
Set tsIn = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\Input.csv")
Set tsOut = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\output.csv")

Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
    TheLine = tsIn.ReadLine
    If TheLine <> "" Then
        If dic.Exists(TheLine) Then
            Repeat = True
        Else
            Repeat = False
            dic.Add TheLine, TheLine
        End If
    Else
        Repeat = False
    End If
    If Not Repeat Then tsOut.WriteLine TheLine
Loop

tsIn.Close
tsOut.Close

Comment: Not sure how to enter code in a good format.

Comment: My current solution is okay for txt files.. but not of csv or excel. I need an array or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

VBA may not be necessary. Helper Columns are your friend here. Try the below formulas

1. assuming `Column6` is `E` and `Column 8` is `G` and the below helper columns are starting in `Column9` / `H`
2. if you have your data in a `DataTable`, you have another syntax option

**R1C1**

- `=Concatenate( E2, F2, G2 )` <-- `H`
- `=Concatenate( E2, G2 )` <-- `I`
- `=CountIfs( I:I, I2 )` <-- `J`
- `=Row()` <-- `K`
- `=IF( J2=1, H1, INDEX(H:H, AGGREGATE( 15,6,K:K/--(I:I=I2), 1 ) ) )` <-- `L`

Column `L` will return the first found row value in Column `H` for the unique concatenate value in Column `I`. If your dataset is very large, the `Index( Aggregate() )` method may overflow and fail. But assuming it works, you can `Copy-Paste Values Only` from Column `L` into a new worksheet and Remove Duplicates ( `Alt`+`A`+`M` to bring up the dialogue ). If you delimit the concatenation in Column `H`, it will help to split out the values back into columns in the new worksheet.

Comment: A bit too lazy to post the DataTable syntax on the first pass ( sorry ). If you are using formatted DataTables and cannot figure out the conversion to stabilize the `Index( Aggregate() )` method, please let me know and I will edit the answer accordingly.